SNMP Error in packet. Reason: noAccess response from supermicro IPMI
I am trying to get Supermicro IPMI sensors data with SNMP
I'am using Debian 12
So i download all mib files that i could find.
Using snmptranslate to see is my machine can understands what this oid means
snmptranslate -Td 1.3.6.1.4.1.21317.1.14.2.1.11
ATEN-IPMI-MIB::fanRPM1
fanRPM1 OBJECT-TYPE
  -- FROM       ATEN-IPMI-MIB
  SYNTAX        Integer32 (1..2147483647)
  MAX-ACCESS    read-only
  STATUS        current
  DESCRIPTION   "PSU Fan RPM1."
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) private(4) enterprises(1) aten(21317) ipmi(1) powerinfo(14) psuTable(2) psuEntry(1) 11 }

than im trying to get information for same sensor from my IPMI with
snmpwalk -m /usr/share/snmp/mibs/IPMI-SNMP-Agent.mib -v 2c -c public IP 1.3.6.1.4.1.21317.1.14.2.1.11
Error in packet.
Reason: noAccess
ATEN-IPMI-MIB::fanRPM1 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID

but i get those errors.
What i am doing wrong?

What is running there at the "public IP" you referred to? The device vendor should be contacted to know what MIB documents are necessary to properly manage it. I strongly go against doing this on your own because usually it is challenging for you to know enough.

the IP part is the IP of the ipmi instead of 10.10.10.10 for example i wirote IP
-c public is part of snmp v1, v2 its like secret word so random people can not read your sensor data.
I downloaded all of the MIB files from supermicro website (https://www.supermicro.com/en/solutions/management-software/bmc-resources here at resource section )

it is a IPMI bmc board on supermicro server.
I found all snmp files from their site and put them on different folders inside /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ directory. I guess i have problem with that noAcess reason.

Message from SuperMicro support team:
The error message you received appears to be because you do not have a DCMS license.
